# How can you stop Chrome from putting suggestions in the url bar? Just in the bar, not below

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a way to stop Chrome from putting suggestions in the url bar? I want the suggestions to appear below the url bar, but not inside it where I'm typing. Having the suggested completion appear in inverted colors makes typing miserable, and I find the inverted color suggestion hard to read.

This is not a duplicate of how to remove a particular suggestion or how to stop suggestions altogether. I only want Chrome to leave the url bar alone while I'm typing; I want the suggestions in the dropdown list to stay.

Comment: Alynurly's answer below seemed to work for awhile; but now, with the options "use a prediction service to help complete searches and urls typed in the address bar" and "use a prediction service to load pages more quickly" disabled as described in that answer, I still get autocomplete in the url/search bar.

Answer (score 1):

To disable autocomplete in general

- open the Chrome Settings
- Show advanced settings (at the bottom)
- Under Privacy, uncheck

  - "Use a prediction service to help complete searches and URLs typed in the address bar."
  - use a prediction service to load pages more quickly

The completions will still appear as dropdown items and you can arrow down to select them - if you want to, but they won't be automatically applied.

- reference: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95656?hl=en

Comment: As of 2020 this is simply not true. The suggestions which appear below the address bar are much less helpful when this is turned off, if any appear at all.